# ListView in Fragment not covering full Parent

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have a ListView in a Fragment which isn't covering the whole Parent when the List isn't fully populated.
The Problem is the scrolling behaviour of the ListView, I can only browse in the small piece of window the ListView is initially loaded in.
(4 Entries or more do occupy the entire Parent, with less entries the problem happens)
[image: Screenshot]

Fragment:

```
    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   >
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:divider="@null"

        />       </LinearLayout>
```

Main XML:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout   
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" 
    />

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:itemBackground="@color/bgBottomNavigation"
        app:itemIconTint="@android:color/white"
        app:itemTextColor="@android:color/white"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation" />


    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

The ListView gets populated via Volley + JSON with an Adapter for the ListView. Comment if you need the Code.

When I'm trying to put the ListViews height on "match_parent" the whole screen is occupied by the ListView, but it isn't scrollable anymore.

What can I do?

EDIT:

Coordinator Layout - This is the Code of the Frame Coordinator with the Bottom Navigation in it:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />



    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:itemBackground="@color/bgBottomNavigation"
        app:itemIconTint="@android:color/white"
        app:itemTextColor="@android:color/white"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation" />

  </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could set a minimum height attribute to your listView and adjust to what suits you.
Eg. to set it to 20dp, add `android:minHeight="20dp"` to your listView attributes.

Best solution would be to wrap all the contents of the `CoordinatorLayout` inside a layout you can control yourself, like a `ConstraintLayout`. In that case you would align the FrameLayout (and the fragments it handles) between your other components and everything would be scrollable and clickable. A mock of this solution would be:

```
<CoordinatorLayout>
    <ConstraintLayout height="match_parent">
        <BottomNavigation bottomToBottomOf="parent" />

        <FrameLayout height="0dp"
            topToTopOf="parent"
            bottomToTopOf="bottomNavigation" />
    </ConstraintLayout>
</CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: well this only stuis for a certain screen size.

Comment: Looks like I have to populate the listview somehow

Comment: @LosKayos, have a look at my edit. Maybe it covers your case better now.

Comment: Thanks for your time! While I try that check my Edit, I already have everything in a Coordinator-Layout. I'll get back with the results

Comment: The problem is still there, but I observed something: The height of the ListView at the beginning is still ok. After the Pictures in the ListView get loaded, the height of the ListView isn't ok anymore. Should I get the height of the images first anmd add them to the height,before loading the listview into the Layout?

Comment: @LosKayos ListView should take care of that for you, can you post an image showing the before and after?

Comment: Ok, to give you a feeling of the new behaviour I did some testing (sorry it took so long, look at my edit)

Comment: I wrote an answer to it because we're on a good way.. Now the only problem (even if it isn't a total killer) is when the View loads only one Thread. Can we fix this in some manner?